# Run a flask python app on apache server

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I am running an Amazon EC2 micro instance and I want to run a python app from it using Flask.

Here is my `app.py` file where I'm doing a simple file upload (it works fine on `localhost:5000`):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from Flask!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Here is my file named `adapter.wsgi` to connect it to apache:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/lumos')

from app import app as application
```

Finally, in my `httpd.conf` file, I have done the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName http://lumos.website.me
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lumos

WSGIDaemonProcess lumos threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/lumos/adapter.wsgi
        <Directory "/var/www/html/lumos">
                WSGIProcessGroup lumos
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then when I restart the apache server and go to http://lumos.website.me/, all I get is a 503:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at lumos.website.me Port 80
```

Any ideas on how I can get the flask app to work on the apache server?

Note: My server is running.

Update:

Here is my error log file

```
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:09 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:09 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:09 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:09 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:10 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.29 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:14 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=30315): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'lumos' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.30311.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:14 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=30316): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'lumos' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.30311.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts., referer: http://lumos.website.me/
[Thu Aug 04 01:34:15 2016] [error] [client 72.219.147.5] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=30317): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'lumos' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.30311.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: Yes, I've updated it in my question

Comment: Add this to your httpd file below </Directory> "<IFMODULE mod_limitipconn.c>
    MaxConnPerVhost 100
</IFMODULE>" and then restart Apache and see if it works?

Comment: Check the apache error log, if needed increase the loglevel.

Comment: @error2007s I got a syntax error `<IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules`

Comment: @KlausD. which apache log do i check? In `/var/log/httpd/`, I have  `error_log`,
 `error_log-20160710`,
 `error_log-20160717`,
 `error_log-20160724`,
and `error_log-20160731`

Comment: Remove "http://" from the server name and restart apache

Comment: Your log is being rotated. You have one current file and several archived versions with a date. Chech the one without date.

Comment: @error2007s still the same 503 error

Comment: I am getting a blank screen for your domain.

Comment: I've updated my question with the errors in the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so looking at the error logs helped me figure out my answer.

Since my error was:

```
(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=30315): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'lumos' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.30311.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

I added this `WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi` in my httpd.conf file and restarted apache.

For other people who may have the same problem as me in the future, here is a more detailed explanation of my error:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationIssues.wiki#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

Answer (score 1):

> Please make sure in advance that any app.run() calls you might have in your application file are inside an if **name** == '**main**': block or moved to a separate file. Just make sure it’s not called because this will always start a local WSGI server which we do not want if we deploy that application to mod_wsgi.

above is extract from http://flask.pocoo.org,  it seems happen with you.